# Как получить результат работы асинхронной функции?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 функции:

```
function getUser () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve({role: "somerole", id: 1})
  })
}

function getUserProfile () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve({name: "Ivan", age: 15})
  })
}
```

Но обе эти ф-и находятся в отдельном файле, доступа к которому у меня нет. Мне нужно получить результат работы ф-и `getUserProfile`, а конкретно поле `age`.
Я пытался сделать вот так:

```
const {getUser, getUserProfile} = require('./Helper.js');

async function getAge() {
    let {name, age} = await getUserProfile();
    return age;
}
```

Но выдает ошибку

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `name` of 'undefined' or
> 'null'.

Сам вопрос: как можно получить значение поля `age`?

Comment: Приведенный в вопросе код такой ошибки выдавать не будет. Приведите воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что если я воспроизвожу этот код локально через своё IDE, то все отрабатывает правильно, но если я этот же код пытаюсь вставить не в IDE, а на сайте с заданием, то появляется эта ошибка. Может это быть из-за того, что я пытаюсь получить значения, когда ф-я ещё не закончила свою работу?

Comment: Если функция действительно возвращает промис, то `await` будет ждать его разрешения, тут у Вас все нормально. Другое дело, что промис может ресолвиться и в `undefined`. Например, если в приведенном примере заменить `resolve({name: "Ivan", age: 15})` на `resolve()`, то как раз и получите это самое "Cannot destucture property..."